# Calculate point at distance between two coordinates

Tags: coordinates, geospatial, geo

Given two points `A` and `B` and a distance `d`, I'm trying to calculate a point `C` between `A` and `B` and at distance `d` from point `A`.

[image]

I was thinking on using Thales theoreme, but is there a better/simpler solution?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Sure the Thales' (Intercept) Theorem is a suitable method, and a degenerate case of that theorem applies when one of the two intersecting lines is a coordinate axis (for example: latA)

So, the steps would be:

```
set a variable to the delta rise: deltalat = latB - latA 
set a variable to the delta run: deltalng = lngB - lngA 
compute the full (pythagorean) distance from A to B:  dist = sqrt(deltalat*deltalat + deltalng*deltalng) 
compute angle from horizontal: ang= arcsin(deltalat/dist)
compute new lat: latC = latA + (d * sin(ang))
compute new lng: lngC = lngA + (d * cos(ang))
```

I went through that a bit quickly in my head, so double-check my trig, please.